# Use ColorFunction in ListLinePlot with If

Tags: plotting, color

The following code

```
ListLinePlot[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[x <= 3, Blue, Red]]]
```

should produce blue lines for $x\le3$ and red lines for $x\ge3$. But instead, the plot contains only blue lines.

Where are my red lines?

Comment: `ColorFunctionScaling`

Comment: Why should I use `ColorFunctionScaling`? My specific color function delivers `Blue` or `Red` – two well defined color directives.

Comment: @Deniz B/c ColorFunctionScaling prevents the scaling of the argument, not of the function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
ListLinePlot[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[x <= 3, Blue, Red]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick, Mesh -> All, 
MeshStyle -> {Orange, PointSize[0.03]}, PlotRange -> 13, 
Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: `Mesh` is a substitute for `PlotMarkers`? Didn't know that!

Comment: How to make this color change according to the given values on the same line? For example, smaller values light color and greater values darker colors?

Comment: @Naps You can just use dark and light version of a single color. Change the `ColorFunction` in above code with a function like this `Function[{x, y}, If[x <= 3, Lighter@Blue, Darker@Blue]]` .

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to drive Brett's and belisarius's point home. Let's modify your original code a bit so we can see exactly what things are passed to your `ColorFunction`:

```
Reap[ListLinePlot[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12},
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Sow[x]; If[x <= 3, Blue, Red]]]]
```

We obtain your erroneous plot as the first component of a list, and the list of all the values passed to your `ColorFunction`: `{{0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.}}` as the second component. Effectively, what was done is to apply `Rescale[]` to the original list you plotted (i.e. `Rescale[N@{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}]`). That's because `ColorFunctionScaling` is by default set to `True`:

```
Options[ListLinePlot, ColorFunctionScaling]
{ColorFunctionScaling -> True}
```

Let's see what happens if we disable `ColorFunctionScaling`:

```
ListLinePlot[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[x <= 3, Blue, Red]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: doubly-colored ListLinePlot]

Note the nice purplish shade in between 3 and 4, showing that the color interpolation is working nicely.

Comment: How would one go about removing the color interpolation?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Mesh` + `MeshShading`

```
ListLinePlot[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[0], 
 Mesh -> {{3}}, MeshShading -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

If you need to add `PlotMarkers`

```
Show[%, ListPlot[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, PlotStyle->Green,  PlotMarkers-> {Automatic, 16}]]
```

[image]