# ColorFunction causing division by zero error (going outside domain?)

Tags: plotting, color

On the following plot example, I get a division by zero error (10.4.1):

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][1/x]]]
(*Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>*)
```

while there seems to be no problem with the ColorFunction:

```
Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][1/x]] @@@ {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}
```

[image]

For what I could get, this is true also for other type of plots.

We can try to do the scaling ourselves (not that with the way it is defined this should matter).

```
MinMax[1/#[[1]] & /@ {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}]
(*{1/2, 1}*)

Rescale[1/#[[1]], MinMax[{1/2, 1}]] & /@ {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}
(*{1, 0}*)
```

But it works:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][
 Rescale[1/x, MinMax[1/#[[1]] & /@ {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}]]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

What's going on? It seems that Mathematica is defining the color scale outside the plot range. If so, why?

Comment: It does seem to be the fault of the internal scaling. Running `Trace[]` on the plot shows that an expression like `(Blend["TemperatureMap", 1/#1] &) @@ {1. (#1 - 1.), 1. (#2 - 1.), 1. (#3 - 1.)} &` is being evaluated at your points, and that will indeed choke on `{1, 1, 1}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use ColorFunction in ListLinePlot with If](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6986/use-colorfunction-in-listlineplot-with-if). Also related: [(21684)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21684/controlling-colorfunctionscaling) and [(23840)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23840/colorfunction-based-on-data/23846#23846).

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior since the values are all rescaled to lie between 0 and 1 prior to feeding them to the `ColorFunction`.  So there will always be some portion of the plotted region that corresponds to a value of 0 and a region that corresponds to a value of 1.

Look at this simplified example,

```
DensityPlot[2 + UnitStep[x], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Which[# == 0, Black, # == 1, White, True, Red] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The function value is either 2 or 3 at every point in the range, but the `ColorFunction` only sees values of either 0 or 1.

You need to turn [`ColorFunctionScaling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html) to `False` in order for the colors to work the way you want them to

```
ListPointPlot3D[Array[{#, #, #} &, 10], 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][1/x]],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> #] & /@ {True, False}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice you get the right colors here,

```
ColorData["TemperatureMap"][1/#] & /@ Range[10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]