# ColorFunction or PlotStyle Based on List

Tags: plotting, color, style

I am plotting the values of a continuous, but complicated function `Energy[x_]` via `ListLinePlot`. Another function `SpinVal[x_]` also gives me values between `-1` and `+1`.

I want the `ListLinePlot` curve of `Energy[x_]` to become blue when `SpinVal[x_]` returns `-1`, red when it returns `+1` and respective colours between blue and red for any values between `-1` and `+1`.

For `ListPlot` the following does the job (with example functions in the P.S.):

```
values = {#, Energy[#]} & /@xRange;
spins = SpinVal/@xRange;

ListPlot[{#} & /@values, PlotStyle -> Hue /@ (0.7 + 0.3/2*(1 + spins))]
```

(The `(0.7 + 0.3/2*(1 + [...])`-part is necessary for my choice of colours, since `0.7` is blue and `1` is red.)

This method, however, does not work for `ListLinePlot`, as it separates the points (see the (`{#} & /@values`)-part inside the plot function). I have made several attempts, e.g. something like what is recommended [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6986/use-colorfunction-in-listlineplot-with-if), but since I want my function to be applicable to more plots than just this one, and since I have a terribly large amount of data points, I feel the need of an easier solution.

Ultimately, an elegant way to generate a legend would also be good. However, this legend can be generated easily by hand if no such elegant method exists.

**P.S.**

My code example above becomes quite illustrative if one just assumes a sine function for both `Energy[x_]` and `SpinVal[x_]`:

```
xRange = Range[-4, 4, 0.1];
values = {#, Sin[#]} & /@ xRange;
spins = Sin /@ xRange;

ListLinePlot[{#} & /@ values, PlotStyle -> Hue /@ (0.7 + 0.3/2*(1 + spins))]
```

It then looks like the following:

[image]

Of course, my actual problem does not have its colour grading matching the actual behaviour of the curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [MarcoB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27951/marcob) I was able to create a function that does the job:

```
xRange = Range[-4, 4, 0.1];
testvalues = {#, Sin[#]} & /@ xRange;
spins = Sin /@ xRange;

ListLinePlot[testvalues, ColorFunction -> (
 Blend[{Green, Red}, Rescale[spins[[1 + Round[#1*(-1 + Length@xRange)]]], {-1, 1}]] &)]
```

[image]

I am not too familiar with the mechanisms behind the `ListLinePlot` function, so there could be some errors. However, this does give the desired result.

`#1` runs from `0` to `1` in `Length@xRange`-many steps *twice*. If you write `Echo[#1]` in my function above, you see what I mean. There will be two sequences from `0` to `1`. I do not know the purpose of the second sequence.

The trick here is to just map these steps on the indices of `xRange` or `spins` (since both have the same length) via a multiplication. `Round` is necessary to make the index an integer.

If one chooses `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` (natively, it is true), `#1` takes all values of `xRange`. However, I found it easier to work with scaling on.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a start, using the made up functions you suggested. I am using red and green as the two colors to mix to highlight the differences (red and blue was not very visible).

```
ClearAll[energy, spin]
energy[x_] := Cos[x]
spin[x_] := Sin[x]

Plot[
  energy[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Green}, Rescale[spin[#2], {-1, 1}]] &)
]
```

[image: plot of function colored by the value of another function there]

Comment: Thank you! I have managed to make your function take its values from a list. Since I should probably say something about it, I will post it as a separate answer.

Comment: @Fred Great! Glad it helped!